# foreach into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to upload the results of an array into a DB table.

```
foreach ($f_list as $list) {
   echo '<a href="http://facebook.com/'.$list['id'] . '"><br>';
   echo $list['name'] . '</a><br>';
 }
```

I want the name and UID to upload into my db.  How can i accomplish this with a foreach method?

Comment: why would someone vote this down???  I have looked up and down for the answer before i posted here... kindly explain your reason

Comment: You can accomplish this using SQL `INSERT` query.

Comment: I know how to upload data using sql connections.  When i attempt to do it i only get the last record of the foreach

Comment: your SQL query s|b inside your foreach

Comment: @islandmyth yeah, if you don't care about performance. You better build a proper query to insert multiple rows at once from an array of data.

Comment: @DmitryScriptin I agree with you. This is easier when you use framework though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql=array();
foreach ($f_list as $list) {
   //This assumes, your values are already safely quoted
   $sql[]="'".$list['id']."','".$list['name']."'";
}
$sql=implode('),(',$sql);
$sql="INSERT INTO tablename VALUES($sql)";
// now run the query
```

Comment: Not really sure why this was closed as you seemed to answer it perfectly and now i have a working sccript... some mods on here are just idiots

Answer (score 0):

Watch in to direction of [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). It simplifies most common security issues and easy to use. Alternative is to simply use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), which is mostly part of PHP library and is on many servers installed by default.